# Change PivotChart source from one PivotTable (external data source) to another PivotTable (table/range)

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2016, pivot-table, pivot-chart

I have a PivotChart in Excel 2016 that is currently based on PivotTable-A.

[image]

PivotTables `A` and `B` are identical, other than the fact that they have different data sources:

- `A`'s data source is an external data source connection.
- `B`'s data source is an Excel table.

I want to change the PivotChart's source from PivotTable-A to PivotTable-B. Once I do that, I'll delete PivotTable-A.

Explanation: [Change PivotTable source from external data source connection to table/range](https://superuser.com/questions/1766508/change-pivottable-source-from-external-data-source-connection-to-table-range)

---

**Question:**

Is there a way to change the PivotChart's source from one PivotTable (external data source) to another PivotTable (table/range)?

I have several PivotCharts where I need to do this. I'd prefer to avoid recreating all the PivotCharts from scratch if I can help it.

---

**Edit:**

Regarding `Analyze >> Change Data Source`:

If the existing data source is an external data source connection, then the option to change the data source to a table/range is greyed out:

[image]